# Tinymce not terminating br

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Im using TinyMce on the webpage. Now the field also must be able to be saved as pdf. For that i have a plugin. But tinymce does not terminate its br elements. The bogus ... thing is in br tag and it does not have a ending tag. So i keep getting error with it.

This is how init currently looks like. Any syggestions how to fore it to add / to br?

```
        selector: select,
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        plugins: "textcolor autoresize",
        min_height: 10,
        height: 10,
        resize: false,
        forced_root_block_attrs: { "style": "margin:0px;" },
        autoresize_bottom_margin : 0,
        autoresize_min_height: 10,
        element_format: 'xhtml',
        encoding: 'xml',
        doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">',
```

Comment: have you tried adding a `.replace("<br>","<br/>")` after getting the content from tinyMce?

Comment: I would but the initial br is <br data-mce-bogus="1">. So i need more generic solution.

Comment: How are you getting data from TinyMCE?  Are you using `editor.getContent()` with a format of `raw`?

Comment: Yes i need raw.